# How can I order by partii.id?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE VIEW v_punkt(partii, turniir, mangija, varv, punkt) AS
SELECT Partii.id, Partii.Turniir, Partii.Must, 'M', (Partii.Musta_tulemus/2.0) FROM Partii
UNION
SELECT Partii.id, Partii.Turniir, Partii.Valge, 'V', (Partii.Musta_tulemus/2.0) FROM Partii
ORDER BY partii.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not in ANSI SQL. (Views are un-ordered.)

You have to add `ORDER BY` when you select from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this, if you add `TOP 100 PERCENT` to your query:

```
CREATE VIEW v_punkt(partii, turniir, mangija, varv, punkt) AS

SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT FROM
(SELECT Partii.id, Partii.Turniir, Partii.Must, 'M', (Partii.Musta_tulemus/2.0) FROM Partii
UNION
SELECT Partii.id, Partii.Turniir, Partii.Valge, 'V', (Partii.Musta_tulemus/2.0) FROM Partii) v
ORDER BY id;
```

I've missed that RDBMS was not mensioned. This works only in MSSQL. I can't tell about other RDBMSes.

Comment: That's product specific SQL, and no dbms is specified.